# No workflow Odoo 10 Community edition

Tags: odoo-10

I installed the Sales app in Odoo 10 Community version, activated developer mode. However, when I navigate to Settings -> Technical Features -> Workflow -> Workflow there is no workflow listed.

Please Help..

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Workflow has been removed from Sales and Purchase in Odoo10

[Bloopark Blog Workflow Odoo10](http://bloopark.de/en_US/blog/the-bloopark-times-english-2/post/odoo-10-workflows-partial-removal-265)